# Как программно задать gravity для TextView в RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть  TextView мне нужно программно  менять гравити для этой вьюхи.

Пробовал сделать так :

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Но не нашел в них  гравити. Попробовал сделать так:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

но кинуло ошибку:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

Вопрос: как можно задать гравити в моем случае?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_main_word"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="customer acquisition cost"
    android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Похоже](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804411/android-relative-layout-problem-with-gravity#comment11192113_2804411), что нельзя в `RelativeLayout` `Gravity` пользовать. Так что придётся вам обходиться атрибутами типа

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

или

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Программно их можно назначать вот [таким](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7234247/3212712) образом методом `addRule`:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);  Таким способом вся верстка  плывет, а вот .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) работает норм, но я хотел бы устанавливать через .setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: @KirillStoianov, у вашего textView ширина во весь экран. Из-за этого текст, по умолчанию, слева экрана находится. setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) установит расположение текста внутри textView, а не его расположение внутри RelativeLayout.

Comment: так мне это и нужно

Comment: @KirillStoianov, вы меня запутали. Вам надо было просто текст посередине расположить внутри текстового поля?..

Comment: ну да. надо текст спозиционировать.

Comment: @KirillStoianov, ну тогда да, через setGravity делайте...